# Error starting application with POW - Bundler::GemNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rvm, rack-pow

I'm using Anvil to manage my local sites. I have several and they all work fine apart from one, my most recent site.

The error i get when i attempt to start it is:

`Error starting application`
`Your Rack app raised an exception when Pow tried to run it.`
`Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find execjs-2.2.2 in any of the sources`

Here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.1.4'

gem 'sqlite3', group: :development

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'

gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'turbolinks'

gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'

gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

gem 'spring',        group: :development

gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"
gem "simple_form"
gem "httparty"
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
gem 'pg', group: :production
```

I've had a look through questions on SO and google but haven't been able to figure it out.

I'm using RVM version 1.25.28

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

This issue seemed to be a result of RVM. I didn't have to do this is any of my other projects but for this one I did the following in order to load RVM into the app's .powrc file:

1. create `.powrc` file in root directory
2. Add this:

   ```
   if [ -f "$rvm_path/scripts/rvm" ]; then
      source "$rvm_path/scripts/rvm"

     if [ -f ".rvmrc" ]; then
      source ".rvmrc"
     fi

     if [ -f ".ruby-version" ]; then
      rvm use `cat .ruby-version`
     fi

     if [ -f ".ruby-gemset" ]; then
      rvm gemset use --create `cat .ruby-gemset`
     fi
   fi
   ```
3. save

And that's it

Hopefully this may be of use in the future to others

Cheers

Comment: alternatively, adding this `source "${rvm_path}/scripts/rvm"
cd .` to the `.powrc` file works too